# Java 8 Lambda Can't Call Default Interface Methods

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I tried to use a interface (a Mapper) being extended by default methods. While stripping down the problem it seems that from the normal lambda syntax one can not access default methods of the interface being instantiated. This is quite undesirable.

Can someone verify this? Is there a work around? Is this problem already known to the Java folks at Oracle?

```
public class LambdaTest {

@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map((number) -> {return Long.valueOf(number);}, 10));

    //Fails on convert: The method convert(Integer) is undefined for the type LambdaTest
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map((number) -> {return convert(number);}, 10));

    //Works
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map(new Mapper<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long map(Integer number) {
            return convert(number);
        }
    }, 10));

    //Fails on this: The method convert(Integer) is undefined for the type LambdaTest
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map((number) -> {return this.convert(number);}, 10));

    //Works
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map(new Mapper<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long map(Integer number) {
            return this.convert(number);
        }
    }, 10));

    //Fails on Mapper.this: No enclosing instance of the type LambdaTest.Mapper<T> is accessible in scope
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map((number) -> {return Mapper.this.convert(number);}, 10));

    //Fails on Mapper.this: No enclosing instance of the type LambdaTest.Mapper<T> is accessible in scope
    assertEquals((Long)10L, map(new Mapper<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long map(Integer number) {
            return Mapper.this.convert(number);
        }
    }, 10));
}

public <T> T map(Mapper<T> mapper, int number) {
    return mapper.map(number);
}

interface Mapper<T> {
    T map(Integer number);
    default Long convert(Integer number) { return Long.valueOf(number);}
}
}
```

Comment: It is a duplicate. Was not able to find it. The explaination is unexpected and makes almost no sense (since it can be expressed using the old anonymous way) but maybe there are other effects and requirements I am not aware of. So this is a duplicate and therefore solved.

Comment: From dup answer: The meaning of names inside a lambda (including the often-implicit name 'this') was one of the most extensively discussed topics in the JSR-335 Expert Group. The two positions could effectively be described as "lambdas are objects" and "lambdas are functions". Ultimately the "lambdas are functions" approach was chosen; it is semantically simpler and admits far deeper optimization. The downside of this choice is that many users are used to the (complex!) semantics of inner classes, and are often surprised to find out that lambdas don't work exactly the same way.

Comment: It is a pity... . For me it breaks the language since you can express a lambda as a inner anonymous class as its equivalent but they are not equivalent. Takes a lot of power unnecessarily out of it since you can not use default methods with interfaces.